# Как правильно обрабатывать Exception по паттерну MVVM?

Tags: c#, mvvm

Допустим, при работе Model вылетел Exception. Я хочу запросить пользователя попытаться снова выполнуть ту функцию, которую запросил пользователь, или остановить работу. Но ведь ViewModel не может напрямую отправлять запросы пользователю. Насколько я понимаю, в его распоряжении только Binded properties и ICommand's. Как правильно обработать Exception?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/910256/222542

Comment: Реализуйте валидацию